# uWSGI Application Error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I followed this [tutorial](https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/python-uwsgi/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin) to the letter but I'm getting the following error.

---

## uWSGI Error

Python application not found

---

Here are my configuration files:

1. /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com (which is symlikned to ../sites-enabled/example.com)

   ```
   server {
       listen          80;
       server_name     $hostname;
       access_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
       error_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log;

   location / {
       #uwsgi_pass      127.0.0.1:9001;
       uwsgi_pass      unix:///run/uwsgi/app/sofitu.com/example.com.socket;
       include         uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
       uwsgi_param     SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

   }

   location /static {
       root   /srv/www/example.com/public_html/static/;
       index  index.html index.htm;

   }

   }
   ```
2. /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/example.com.xml (symlinked to ../apps-enabled/example.com.xml)

   ```
   <uwsgi>
       <plugin>python</plugin>
       <socket>/run/uwsgi/app/example.com/example.com.socket</socket>
       <pythonpath>/srv/www/example.com/application/</pythonpath>
       <app mountpoint="/">

       <script>wsgi_configuration_module</script>

       </app>
       <master/>
       <processes>4</processes>
       <harakiri>60</harakiri>
       <reload-mercy>8</reload-mercy>
       <cpu-affinity>1</cpu-affinity>
       <stats>/tmp/stats.socket</stats>
       <max-requests>2000</max-requests>
       <limit-as>512</limit-as>
       <reload-on-as>256</reload-on-as>
       <reload-on-rss>192</reload-on-rss>
       <no-orphans/>
       <vacuum/>
   </uwsgi>
   ```
3. /srv/www/example.com/application/wsgi_configuration_module.py

   ```
   import os
   import sys

   sys.path.append('/srv/www/example.com/application')

   os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/srv/www/example.com/.python-egg'

   def application(environ, start_response):
       status = '200 OK'
       output = 'Hello World!'

       response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                       ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
       start_response(status, response_headers)

       return [output]
   ```

---

**I have two questions** that I'll preface by saying I am brand new to both nginx and uWSGI configurations.

1. Obviously, why isn't this working?
2. Where are the uWSGI error logs? Did I need to define their location?

Comment: For logging add <logto>/srv/www/example.com/logs/uwsgi.log</logto> to your xml.  Also, what version uwsgi are you running? Run "uwsgi --version" to check. I had a similar issue that was fixed by using the python version. Installing through apt gives you an old version, 1.1 I think. Installing via pip will get you version 1.9. Pip installs to /usr/bin/local/uwsgi, try typing "/usr/bin/local/uwsgi --version" it should return 1.9. Then just update the BINPATH line in your /etc/init/uwsgi file to "env BINPATH=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi".

Comment: `uWSGI 1.2.3-debian (64bit)` I did install via apt-get. `current working directory: /srv/www/example.com; detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core`

Comment: I added the `<logto>...` line but it didn't create a log.

Comment: run the server from the command line and use a stable version, 1.2.3 is really old (and has known bugs). Once all it works you can join all of the pieces of the infrastructure